# Check to see if eval(string) is in list of objects. In Python

Tags: python, string, object, eval

I have a list of objects.  I have a user inputted string.  I need to check and see if the string is in the list of objects.

For example:

```
string = "book"
object_list = [book, paper, pencil]
if eval(string) in object_list:
  #do this, etc
```

This works as long as the string is in the list.  If the string is something else, like:
string = 'ruler'

Then the `if eval(string)...` statement gives an error:
`NameError: 'ruler' is undefined.`

Comment: Ouch, I mistakenly flagged it as duplicate, please ignore. Well, anyway: See possible duplicate of [Is Using eval In Python A Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do? What *is* `book`, etc.? Suppose you find the item in the `object_list`; then what? Why should the person who is running your program have any idea what your variables are named?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use eval - just umm, either create a dict mapping eg:

```
dispatch = {'book': book, ...}
```

Then use that and let a traceback happen - much more controlled....

or at worst use `globals()`:

```
if globals()[string] in object_list:
    # do something...
```

Comment: I'm new to programming.  Would you mind explaining a bit more?  I've read about the globals function but I don't understand it.  And how would I go about making the dictionary contain the object book in the value position.

Comment: Sure - the best thing you can do is look up `globals()` in the manual, or look up how a `dict` works...

Comment: I've done both.  'Globals: Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table.' That is greek to me.  I've used dictionaries a bit but I wouldn't know how to take a string and convert it to a dictionary containing string keys and object values.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to check if the string is in the list, why dont u just use,

```
if string in object_list:
    #code
```

Comment: because I'd be comparing a string to an object.  If "book" in [book, pencil] returns false.